# Create model from xml and import to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Hello I'm a beginner so any suggestion may be really helpful even non a technical solution but a conceptual way to achieve it, I have a multi sheets .xls file with products I need to search for in my Rails application.

1. What is the most tear-free method to create a model from a xls file?
2. Every sheet page have totally different pagination so i need to make
   a model for each sheet page?

You can see an example file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikx8yvyoj39p8tr/Listino%20TIP%20finto.xls?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data that can be very easy or not. Without knowing your data I suggest exporting them to a CSV format and than use http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html to import them in a `seeds.rb` file.

If CSV is not an option you can use https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet

If I where you I'd start with creating models in Rails. Once you are happy with your models you can import your data. But take your time. You really don't want a quick and dirty version. ActiveRecord needs tidiness.

To get a more precise answer you need to create a new question with concrete example data.

Comment: csv convertion cant be dont as the spreadsheet contains multiple sheets(pages), every page is often edited or new are created, this is something out of my congrol as the xls file is provived by my supplier. personally i would avoid to create models myself, and instead dumb the xsl and use the header for create a model

Comment: I added https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet as a possibility to import spreadsheets.

Comment: Added example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikx8yvyoj39p8tr/Listino%20TIP%20finto.xls?dl=0)